# Polygons requirement on mobile devices, around 3000 vertices?

Tags: unity, performance, blender

I read on the `unity` documentation that a character should be between 300 to 1500 "polygons" on mobile devices to have good results. In `Blender`, we have "tris" or "faces", does "polygon" stand for the "face" here?

Also, my character will have around 2800-3000 vertices, with 10-12 bones. Considering the requirement for 1500 vertices was written some years ago, should I trust in the power of the new mobile devices and continue like this, or should I make a new retopology to reach the 1500 vertices in total? I will not have more than 2 characters on screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing polygons and vertices in your question.

Polygons generally refer to triangles.

As for the load on the graphics, you should probably aim for a "minimum requirement" device and see how it handles your game, graphics wise. This is going to be your maximum number of polys.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me 5500+ tris, which let me no option I guess :)